# Docky customization

Tags: customization, docky, mac

I modded my docky-sources, so i have no reflection anymore. 
Where can i remove the separators or change the metrics like [this](http://illusionmist.deviantart.com/#/d31mrq6)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am using "docky 2.07 release" as seen in the "about" window of my Docky.

[image]

I don't know what exactly you mean with "change the metrics" but the image in your link looks like my docky.

I am using the "HUD" theme, with 3D background and a few more options which can be configured in the settings of Docky.

[image]

[image]
[image]

The separators in my Docky is indicating a separation of the icons and currently open applications and the Docklets/Helpers. I think it can be configured throug modifying the code. You can gain access to the code in the next link:

https://launchpad.net/~docky-core

Some items can be edited by you in order to make something with the backgrounds and other things but as for a certain items (the indicator, reflection, etc.) you should see in the code in order to gain access to the right place. Understanding the code isn't that difficult, give it a try. You may experience problems when compiling but that's for a different Q&A.

Images for the themes can be reached at: `/usr/share/docky/themes`. You will need to `sudo nautilus` before pasting the edited images in that place, a good images editor will help (gimp ie). And as the majority of the images used for themes are .svg I suppose that the separator should also be an image. REMEMBER TO BACKUP!

Good luck!

*BTW: Some of my Docky effects are handled by Emerald Theme Manager.*

Hey! Did you take a look to this?

> ~illusionmist Oct 30, 2010
>   To do all these you'll have to get the source from bzr first...
>
> Remove reflection:  Navigate to
>   docky/Docky/Docky/Interface, open up
>   DockWindow.cs, search for "expensive"
>   (yup). And then comment out the
>   reflection part so it looks like this:
>
> if (ThreeDimensional) { if (item is
>   SeparatorItem) { center =
>   center.MoveIn (Position,
>   -DockHeightBuffer); /*} else { double offset = 2 * Math.Max (Math.Abs
>   (val.Center.X - center.Center.X),
>   Math.Abs (val.Center.Y -
>   center.Center.Y)); offset -= .07 *
>   IconSize * renderZoom;
>   icon.ShowAsReflection (surface,
>   center.Center, renderZoom,
>   renderRotation, opacity, offset,
>   Position);*/ } }
>
> As for indicators there's this
>   CreateIndicatorBuffer function. I
>   tried my best and actually changed it
>   to drawing a triangle instead of tiny
>   radial gradient circles.
>
> Then you build it and install it. The
>   fun of Linux, eh?
>
> (Your Firefox Elementary is so darn
>   sexy, by the way )

Comment: thanks so far.i already removed the reflections and changed the indicator like in the comment but i want to remove the separators completely and change the way it is drawn in 3d (metrics)